# R or Python remove the rows base on variables

Tags: python, r, bash

I have a table like this. I want to select those rows that for each different name `coorrr` is not always bigger than `budget`, or `budget` is always bigger than `coorrr`.

So I want for example just `T` and `Y` as `budget` is sometimes bigger than `coorrr` and `coorrr` is sometimes bigger than `budget` for each name:

```
  cluster load_date  budget  coorrr         name
1       A  2/1/2014   12000   10000           Y
2       A  3/1/2014   36000  290000           Y
3       B  4/1/2014   15000   10000           N
4       B  4/1/2014   12000   11500           N
5       B  4/1/2014   90000   11000           T
6       C  7/1/2014   22000   28000           T
7       C  8/1/2014   30000   28960           T
8       C  9/1/2014   53000   51200           T
```

The code I have so far:

```
import sys
du=[]
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f1: 
    for line in f1: 
        pp = line.split("\t")
    du.append(line.split("\t")[9])
    for aa in du:
        if aa in line and pp[8] > pp[6] or pp[8] < pp[6]:
            pass
        else:
            print line
```

I would be glad if you can help me with either R or Python or Bash,

Comment: unclear what you are asking. Maybe you should add the expected result.

Comment: Can you describe your issue more specifically? I understand what you're trying to do, but what does the code you've posted do? Do you get exceptions or bad results you can share with us? As agstudy said, showing us an example of your desired output would help more than a description in words.

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you want the rows where the `budget` and `coorr` are not equal? `if aa in line and pp[8] > pp[6] or pp[8] < pp[6]:` will return all rows where they are not equal.

Comment: @g.d.d.c BUT the OP has already shown his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (if `dat` is the data)

```
dat[with(dat, !ave(budget>coorrr, name, FUN=all)),]
#     cluster load_date budget coorrr name
#1       A  2/1/2014  12000  10000    Y
#2       A  3/1/2014  36000 290000    Y
#5       B  4/1/2014  90000  11000    T
#6       C  7/1/2014  22000  28000    T
#7       C  8/1/2014  30000  28960    T
#8       C  9/1/2014  53000  51200    T
```

Here, the idea is to group by column `name` using the `ave` function and see if all the elements of inside each `name` are `TRUE` for the logical condition `budget >coorr`.  This should work if you change the condition to `budget <coorr`

For example:

```
  with(dat, budget >coorrr)
  #[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE #Here, the 1st two elements belong to name `Y`, which are not all `TRUE` or all `FALSE`, while 3 and 4 elements from the comparison that belong to `N` are all `TRUE`
  with(dat, budget <coorrr) #Here it got reversed
 #[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

By using `ave` in combination with `all` for the `first` case

```
  with(dat, ave(budget>coorrr, name, FUN=all))
  #[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If all the elements in the group are TRUE, it will remain as `TRUE`, otherwise, the index for the whole group changes to `FALSE`.  Because you want to only subset the rows that have some difference, just negate the above logical index using `!`

```
  with(dat, !ave(budget>coorrr, name, FUN=all))
  #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

and subset it `[`